# Writing a loop script in bash, but keeps failing

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to write a loop script to run 2 jobs at once and keep getting the following errors:

> ./loop_script_test.sh: line 30: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
>
> ./loop_script_test.sh: line 55: syntax error: unexpected end of file

My script is:

```bsh
source /node/procTestData/*/000scratch/*.io/*/logs_workflow/1_*.log

files="/node/procTestData/*/000scratch/*.io/*/logs_workflow/1_*.log |
/node/procTestData/*/*.io/*/logs_workflow/*.log

rundir="/node/procTestData/*/000scratch/ProductionwfTest.io/work* |
/node/procTestData/*/*.io/work*"

exitmessage=$(grep "volume created successfully" $runfile)
error1=$(grep "error" $files)
error2=$(grep "ERROR" $files)
error3=$(grep "SEVERE" $files)
error4=$(grep "severe" $files)
error5=$(grep "Error" $files)
error6=$(grep "Severe" $files)
error7=$(grep "WARNING" $files)
error8=$(grep "Warning" $files)
error9=$(grep "warning" $files)

wait

{
for file in $files
do

if [ ! -e '$files']
then

/d/sw/*/20130927/_ApplicationToRunOnData "'ProductionwfTest.proc' | 'workflow.proc'"

wait

$rundir/run_harness.sh;

wait

echo $files

wait

echo $error1
echo $error2
echo $error3
echo $error4
echo $error5
echo $error6
echo $error7
echo $error8
echo $error9
echo $exitmessage

fi
done
```

Comment: There is no terminating quote - " in line `files="/node/procTestData/*/000scratch/*.io/*/logs_workflow/1_*.log |
/node/procTestData/*/*.io/*/logs_workflow/*.log` is that the typo in the post?

Comment: i've never seen stack overflow answer a question with its own syntax highlighting before.  if this trend continues maybe it can run itself!